# MySQL speed of a table affected by the size of other tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

In a MySQL database with multiple tables, is the runtime of an query on a table affected by the size of all the other tables within the same database?

Comment: its affected by size of the same table for insert and update. But other tables? I am not sure. Only if inserts, updates, selects use the "other tables" I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of two effects that other tables could have on a query, assuming that these tables are not involved in the query, no other queries are running, and there are no constraints or triggers that link the tables.

The first effect is during the compilation phase.  During this phase, the SQL parser is fetching information about tables and columns from metadata tables.  More tables and columns in the database could slow down the compilation of the query.

The other effect is page table and disk fragmentation.  If you have a clean system and start allocating and filling pages, then the pages are probably going to fill contiguous pages on the disk (no guarantees, but probably).  At access time, the operating system might be pre-fetching physical pages adjacent to a requested page.  In the environment I described, this pre-fetched data would probably be used in the query.

In a database with multiple tables, you have a much greater chance of the disk being fragmented.  In this case, the pre-fetched hardware pages are less likely to be for the same tables in the query.  This means that they don't get used, so an additional I/O request is needed to get the next page.

I've described this in terms of disk fragmentation, but a similar thing can happen with the pages themselves.  The physical pages where data for a table is stored may not be contiguous, with similar results.

Fragmentation can be an issue with databases.  In fact, it can be an issue regardless of the number of tables in the database.  But more tables with more insert/delete activity on them tends to increase fragmentation.  However, the effects are usually pretty slight, and would only in certain extreme circumstances be responsible for a significant reduction in performance.

Comment: The disk fragmentation and I/O caching issues are more related to the same server than to the same database, but they should still be considered. Not sure if different databases on the same server can interfere performance wise on query compilation and planning.

Answer (score 1):

Having many tables (and data) only requires an HDD space.

Processing speed depends on your table optimization and size + queries you executing, not an entire database.

Answer (score 1):

Query run-time can be effected by a wide variety of server environment concerns, so while one might say that in and of itself having other large tables in the database wouldn't effect the speed of queries on unrelated tables, the reality is those tables might be getting queried too and consuming server resources. This of course effects your query speed.

Answer (score 1):

It should only be a problem if that table (the large one) is related to the other table with some sort of connection (foreign key constraints would be one example)...otherwise your tables should behave independently.  That said, if you have a single table that is so massive as to be causing speed problems, you might want to find other solutions for refactoring some of that data into smaller subsets.